# How to call a function inside another function ? c++

Tags: c++

I was told to build a function called comparison() to compare two financial plans.
The two financial plans are working perfectly in thier own functions.
How do I call the two functions inside my comparison() function ?

This is the code for the first financial plan.

```
void oneLumpSumWithdrawal( int startingAge, int numOfYears,
                           double lumpSumAmount, double interestRate )
{
    int age = startingAge;
    int lastAge = startingAge + numOfYears;
    double cash = lumpSumAmount;
    cout << "Age | oneLumpSum" << endl;
    cout << "----+----------------" << endl;
    while (age <= lastAge)
        cout.width(3);
    cout << age << " | ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout.precision(2);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout << cash << endl;
    if (age != lastAge)
        cash = cash + cash*interestRate / 100.0;
    age++;

    system("pause");
}
```

This is the code for the second financial plan

```
void yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears, int yearlyAmount, double interestRate)
{
    int age = startingAge;
    int lastAge = startingAge + numOfYears;
    double cash = yearlyAmount;
    cout << "Age | Yearly Plan" << endl;
    cout << "----+----------------" << endl;
    while (age <= lastAge)
    {
        cout.width(3);
        cout << age << " | ";
        cout.width(15);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout << cash << endl;
        if (age != lastAge)
        {
            cash = (cash + cash*interestRate / 100.0) + yearlyAmount;
            age++;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I tried calling it like this but it didn't work.

```
void comparison()
{
  oneLumpSumWithdrawal( startingAge, numOfYears,
                            lumpSumAmount,  interestRate );

  yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears, int yearlyAmount, double interestRate);


}
```

User will call the function in a switch statement inside the main function.

Comment: it didn't work in what sense?

Comment: Don't use `int` in front of variable names when calling the function. Also - are your variable names defined (and do the have a value) when you call the functions? "Inside a function" looks no different than "inside main loop" - except that variables are local unless declared global in scope. If you don't understand that statement it's time to hit the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

`yearlyWithdrawal(int startingAge, int numOfYears, int yearlyAmount, double interestRate);`

But you don't have to include types when calling a function. You have to call

`yearlyWithdrawal( startingAge, numOfYears, yearlyAmount, interestRate);`